# python reads last line only

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
all_courses=open("E:/we/aa.txt","r").readlines()
completed_ones=open("E:/we/aaa.txt","r")
read_completed_ones=completed_ones.readlines()
my_dict={}
my_dict["completed courses"]=read_completed_ones

for line in all_courses:
  if line.strip().startswith("#"):
    continue
  splitted=line.split(",")
  #print splitted
  courses_remaining=splitted[2]
  #print courses_remaining
  for every in read_completed_ones:
     the_big=every
     if courses_remaining==the_big: 
        print courses_remaining
```

my problem is if courses_remaining==the_big, the_big is the last line, i donn know how to make the_big all the line not just the last. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Your code is hard to read with just 2 spaces of indentation. `the_big` is set to each line in `read_completed_ones`, not just the last one, unless you did something wrong to the indentation of the `if` statement following it.

Comment: It sounds to me as if the `if courses_remaining == the_big` indentation is not correct in your *actual* code; make sure it is indented to match the `the_big = every` line. If you are mixing tabs and spaces, don't, that'll only lead to more problems like these.

Comment: the problem is i'm sure that the tabs are correct, but when i print the_big before if courses_remaining==the_big, it print all the lines, but after the if indentation it prints only the last line @MartijnPieters

Comment: Then your indentation does **not** match. The `if` statement is executed after the loop has completed.

Comment: and how do i fix that problem because i can't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the indentation is correct:

```
for every in read_completed_ones:
    the_big=every
    if courses_remaining==the_big: 
        print courses_remaining
```

would be correct, but in your case the indentation is really:

```
for every in read_completed_ones:
    the_big=every
if courses_remaining==the_big: 
    print courses_remaining
```

which means that `the_big` is now referring to the last line.

You probably are mixing tabs and spaces; don't do that. Run your script with `python -tt` to detect any inconsistent tabbing and replace all tabs with spaces in your editor.